# Замена символа Replace

Tags: c#

Как сделать так чтобы в строке заменить все пробелы на плюсы? Желательно с помощью Replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = "sdfa  dsfas  sdfasd".Replace(" ", "+");
```

Answer (score 2):

Еще вариант для Regex.Replace - замена последовательности пробелов на +

```
  Regex rgx = new Regex("\\s+");
  string result = rgx.Replace("Это какой-то тест с пробелами:   ", "+");
```

Comment: Слишком сложно.